# Bluetooth media controls not working windows 10

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth, autohotkey

I have bluetooth headphones synced and playing music from my windows 10 laptop without any problems.

How can I make it possible to pause/play, skip track, previous track controls on the headphones working with windows 10?

I am pretty sure this could/should work as my keyboard is bluetooth and all the controls on that work without problems.

I wonder, if there any way to catch bluetooth singles send with autohotkey?

Answer (score 3):

Click on the Windows Start Button and navigate to the Control Panel. Start up Administrative Tools and click on Services. Scroll down to Human Interface Device Access and ensure the service has started up. If it is not, click on restart the service to the left pane of the window and change it to startup automatically by double clicking the service.

Comment: works here on Windows 10, 64 bit, one can even control web players like YouTube with an extension like this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen

Comment: it's called human device services. Also for powerusers, just run services.msc ...

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/4xdpch/remapping_bluetooth_headset_buttons/) Reddit post with a solution that appears to work with the play/pause.

In addition to that I use the StreamKeys Chrome extension like escalator suggest above. This works more or less fine for me. You may want to tweak it more to suit your needs.

Working .ahk script from the aforementioned Reddit Post:

```
#Include AHKHID.ahk
Gui, +LastFound
hGui := WinExist()
OnMessage(0xFF, "InputMsg")
AHKHID_Register(12, 1,hGui, RIDEV_INPUTSINK)
return

InputMsg(wParam, lParam) {
    Local d
    devhandle:=AHKHID_GetInputInfo(lParam,II_DEVHANDLE)
    data_code:=AHKHID_GetInputData(lParam, uData)
    if (data_code=5) {
       SendInput {Media_Play_Pause}
    }
    return test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your controls don't work if you do not lock the system. But if you do lock it then I can confirm the controls will not work. Some details [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/bluetooth-audio-controls-do-not-work-when-system/95d7ad76-630f-4b19-9cca-5e8aa95ef8dc).
I have talked to a Windows Support staff member and he told me that some people in MS know about the issue but currently there is no evidence that the issue will be addressed.